# JQuery datepicker function for multiple from inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, datepicker

I'm trying to use jquery's datepicker for multiple form fields which I have working when hard coded. I don't know how to do this for a variable number of fields. For example, below I have hard coded it to work for two inputs. I want to do this for any amount of inputs the user provides on a previous page. Thanks for the help!

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="https://www.cvrc.virginia.edu/otherscripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="https://www.cvrc.virginia.edu/otherscripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
      });
      </script>

      <input type=text name=date size=10 id=datepicker>
      <input type=text name=date size=10 id=datepicker2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a common class or use the name with an attribute selector

**JavaScript**

```
$('[name="date"]').datepicker();
```

or

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

**HTML** *if you go with the class selector*

```
 <input type="text" name="date" size="10" id="datepicker" class="datepicker">
 <input type="text" name="date" size="10" id="datepicker2" class="datepicker">
```

Comment: Do they have the same name?