# JQuery datepicker function for dynamic created date inputs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to use jquery's datepicker for dynamic form fields. This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darkkyoun/c8496mpa/19/) that show the issue.

below is my code

```
<div class="box-body" id="collapse1">
 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>
          <red>*</red>
          Full Name (As on NRIC/FIN)
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>
          <red>*</red>
          Gender
        </label>
        <div class="radio row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" id="male"> Male
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" id="female"> Female
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <form-group>
        <label>
          <red>*</red>
          Date Of Birth (DD-MM-YYYY)
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="date" class="datepicker">
      </form-group>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <form-group>
        <label>
          <red>*</red>
          NRIC / FIN
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </form-group>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div id="parent" class="col-md-3">
  <div id="child" class="col-md-3">
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div>
  <button type="button" onclick="addInputLine()">
    press
  </button>
</div>
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. click "press" button
2. A new div with a second date input appears

Expected result: able to pick date for x amount of date input field created

Actual result: date pick on the second input field update the first field

What I have tried: I apply  solution from this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529762/jquery-datepicker-function-for-multiple-from-inputs), it does not work for me

I want to do this for any amount of inputs dynamically created by the user. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The linked SO answer is not for dynamically generated elements.  Init your datepickers *after* you add them.

Comment: how do i init my datepickers ? since i am creating them on the go

Comment: This *should* work as the last line of your `addInputLine()` `$(parent).find(".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd" });`, but the datepicker isn't working in your fiddle - but strangely *does* work if you remove the first init:  https://jsfiddle.net/xpmgLc83/  I think it's because of the way you copy the html - it's copying the `hasDatepicker` class so doesn't re-init as it thinks it's already a datepicker.

Comment: so weird, your soultion work for x amount of input but does not work for the first one hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clone()` for cloning your `collapse1` div . Then , whenever user click on `press` button simply use `.append()` to append new divs inside your `parent` div and then intialize your datepicker using `$("#parent .block:last").find(".datepicker").datepicker({//options})`

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  var target = $("#collapse1").clone(); //keep clone..for further use
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
  });
  //on click of press
  $(".press").on("click", function() {
    $("#parent").append("<br><div class='block'>" + $(target).html() + "</div>") //append block div
    $("#parent .block:last").find(".datepicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
    }); //then intialize your datepicker
  })
});
```

```css
.block {
  border: 2px solid black
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="box-body" id="collapse1">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>
          <red>*</red>
          Full Name (As on NRIC/FIN)
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>
          <red>*</red>
          Gender
        </label>
        <div class="radio row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" class="male"> Male
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" class="female"> Female
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <form-group>
        <label>
          <red>*</red>
          Date Of Birth (DD-MM-YYYY)
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="date" class="datepicker">
      </form-group>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <form-group>
        <label>
          <red>*</red>
          NRIC / FIN
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </form-group>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div id="parent" class="col-md-3">
  <div id="child" class="col-md-3">
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div>
  <button type="button" class="press">
    press
  </button>
</div>
```